# Chained classloader conundrum

Tags: java, classloader

I'm having some hard time with Java classloaders, maybe somebody could shed some light on this. I have extracted the essence of the problem to the follwing:

There are three classes - `ClassLoaderTest`, `LoadedClass` and `LoadedClassDep`. They are all on different paths.

`ClassLoaderTest` instantiates a new `URLClassLoader` - `myClassLoader`, priming it with the paths to the remaining two classes and it's own classloader (i.e. the application classloader) as parent. It then uses `Class.forName("com.example.LoadedClass", true, myClassLoader)` to load the `LoadedClass` through reflection. The `LoadedClass` imports the `LoadedClassDep`. If I run the above, using:

```
java -cp /path/to/the/ClassLoaderTest ClassLoaderTest "/path/to/LoadedClass" "/path/to/LoadedClassDep"
```

and using the command line arguments to prime the `URLClassLoader` everything works fine. Using static initialisers I confirm that the two classes are loaded with an instance of a `URLClassLoader`.
HOWEVER, and this is the problem, if I do:

```
java -cp /path/to/the/ClassLoaderTest:/path/to/the/LoadedClass ClassLoaderTest "/path/to/LoadedClassDep"
```

this fails to load the LoadedClassDep (`ClassNotFoundException`). The `LoadedClass` is loaded correctly, but with `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`, not the `URLClassLoader`!
It would appear that since the application classloader is capable of loading the `LoadedClass` it also attempts to load the `LoadedClassDep`, disregarding the `URLClassLoader`.

Here's the full source code:

`package example.bc;
public class ClassloaderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassloaderTest().run(args);
    }

    private void run(String[] args) {
        URLClassLoader myClasLoader = initClassLoader(args);
        try {
            Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.example.bc.LoadedClass", true, myClasLoader);
            Object obj = cls.newInstance();
            cls.getMethod("call").invoke(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private URLClassLoader initClassLoader(String[] args) {
        URL[] urls = new URL[args.length];

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                urls[i] = new File(args[i]).toURI().toURL();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader());
    }
}

package com.example.bc;

import com.bc.LoadedClassDep;

public class LoadedClass {

    static {
        System.out.println("LoadedClass " + LoadedClass.class.getClassLoader().getClass());
    }

    public void call() {
        new LoadedClassDep();
    }
}

package com.bc;

public class LoadedClassDep {
    static {
        System.out.println("LoadedClassDep " + LoadedClassDep.class.getClassLoader().getClass());
    }
}`

I hope I made this clear enough. My issue is, I only know the path to `ClassLoadeTest` at compile time, I have to use strings at runtime for the other paths. So, any ideas how to make the second scenario work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect the application classloader to load `LoadedClass` in the second case, since classloaders delegate to their parent initially - this is the [standard behaviour](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/load.html).  In the second case, `LoadedClass` is on the parent's classpath, so it loads the class instead of giving up and letting the `URLClassLoader` try.

The application classloader then attempts to load the `LoadedClassDep` because it is imported and referenced directly in `LoadedClass`:

```
public void call() {
    new LoadedClassDep();
}
```

If you need to load these classes dynamically and independently at runtime, you can't have direct references between them in this way.

It is also possible to change the order in which classloaders are tried - see [Java classloaders: why search the parent classloader first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650334/java-classloaders-why-search-the-parent-classloader-first) for some discussion of this.

Comment: That seems to be right. I was hoping that although the `URLClassloader` delegates to the parent, the loaded class would still have it as its classloader, since that's where the call was initiated. But no, it's the AppClassLoader from then on. Thanks

Comment: Here's what I ended up doing - I rigged the `URLClassloader` to only load the `LoadedClass` and the `LoadedClassDep` (of which there are many in the actual program). So it delegates to the parent classloader, unless it's one of the above, in which case it loads them itself. This way the `LoadedClass` has the custom classloader bound to it and asks _it_ to load its dependencies.